# Question about meaning of "determination" in context

Tags: word-meaning

The search co-ordinator insisted the latest developments should be treated as unverified "until such time as we can provide an unequivocal **determination**"."We are working in a very big ocean and within a very large search area, and so far since the aircraft went missing we have had very few leads which allow us to narrow the search area," he said.

http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-26908884

I have checked it in Longman and I have my doubts whether its meaning has to do with second or third definition. Here is the link to Longman. Could you simplify it? 
http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/determination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In very simple language - don't consider anything confirmed unless we come up with some concrete evidence. (However, the quotes ("") at that place do not look natural to me).

*Determination* is not that close to those definitions in this context. I agree with you. Probably this'll help us more -

> [determination (#3)](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/DETERMINATION) - *A position, opinion or judgment reached after consideration*

*[Unequivocal](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=unequivocal)* is without doubt and confirmed.

This might make clear now...

> *...we can provide any judgement without any doubt...*